# Route constraint reference for the param type - list of long

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autorest

I am writing an GET method on my ASP.NET core controller which takes a list of longs as an parameter.

```
[HttpGet("RetrieveAccessorNamesForAccessorIds/{accessorIds}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> RetrieveAccessorNamesForAccessorIds(List<long> accessorIds)
```

I need to write a [route constraint reference](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/routing.md#route-constraint-reference) so [autorest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest) can find the param type when trying to generate packages based off the swagger definition. In the code above, Autorest throws an error as it is unaware of what type to use for the param `accessorIds`.

The issue is I cannot find what route constraint for this scenario as lists are not an option in the documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's valid for a GET request. How would you expect the URL to look like?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto after thinking about your comment, I decided that it made more sense to move the list of longs into the method query params instead of the route. 

Autorest managed to correctly identify the object type from the query params and the problem was solved. Thanks

Comment: You should post that as an answer then, so it help future readers with similar questions